# How to read comma-delimited data with some values using commas between quotes

Tags: matlab, octave, delimiter, textscan

I have a data file that includes comma-delimited data that I am trying to read into Octave. Most of the data is fine, but some includes numbers between double quotes that use commas between the quotes. Here's a sample section of data:

```
.123,4.2,"4,123",700,12pie
.34,4.23,602,701,23dj
.4345,4.6,"3,623,234",700,134nfg
.951,68.5,45,699,4lkj
```

I've been using `textscan` to read the data (since there's a mix of number and strings), specifying comma delimiters, and that works most of the time, but occasionally the file contains these bigger integers in quotes scattered through that column. I was able to get around one of these quoted numbers earlier in the data file because I knew where it would be, but it wasn't pretty:

```
sclose = textscan(fid, '%n %n', 1, 'delimiter', ',');
junk = fgetl(fid, 1);
junk = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '"');
junk = fgetl(fid, 1);
sopen = textscan(fid, '%n %s', 1, 'delimiter', ',');
```

I don't care about the data in that column, but because it changes size and sometimes contains the quoted with extra commas that I want to ignore, I'm struggling with how to read/skip it. Any suggestions on how to handle it?

Here's my current (ugly) approach that reads the column as a string, then uses `strfind` to check for a " within the string. If it's present then it reads another comma-delimited string and repeats the check until the closing " is found and then resumes reading the data.

```
fid = fopen('sample.txt', 'r');
for k=1:4
  expdata1(k, :) = textscan(fid, '%n %n %s', 1, 'delimiter', ',');  #read first 3 data pts
  qcheck = char(expdata1(k,3));
  idx = strfind(qcheck, '"');  #look for "
  dloc = ftell(fid);
  for l=1:4
    if isempty(idx) #if no " present, continue reading data
      break
    endif
    dloc = ftell(fid);  #save location so can return to next data point
    expdata1(k, 3) = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', ',');  #if " present, read next comma segment and check for "
    qcheck = char(expdata1(k,3));
    idx = strfind(qcheck, '"');
  endfor
  fseek(fid, dloc);
  expdata2(k, :) = textscan(fid, '%n %s', 1, 'delimiter', ',');
endfor
fclose(fid);
```

There's gotta be a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this has a matlab tag on it, are you using matlab textscan or octave?

If in matlab, I would suggest using either [readmatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) or [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html).

Also note, the format specifier for quoted string is `%q`. This should be applicable to both languages even for `textscan`.

Putting your sample data in `data.csv`, the following is possible:

```matlab
>> readtable("data.csv", 'Format','%f%f%q%d%s');
ans =

  4×5 table

     Var1     Var2        Var3         Var4       Var5   
    ______    ____    _____________    ____    __________

     0.123     4.2    {'4,123'    }    700     {'12pie' }
      0.34    4.23    {'602'      }    701     {'23dj'  }
    0.4345     4.6    {'3,623,234'}    700     {'134nfg'}
     0.951    68.5    {'45'       }    699     {'4lkj'  }
```

Comment: %q works and is SO MUCH MORE elegant! Thank you, not sure how I missed that in the documentation. I'm using Octave, but with the program similarities I figured Matlab might get a bit more input and be applicable.